# Can't get PDO to work with my old drop down

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've been trying to work through some PDO tutorials and apply them to my site but nothing seems to work including, I suspect, what is left of my sanity.. I have a search page which has the following drop down form which was written in older PHP. I haven't been able to find how to rewrite this in PDO but I suspect they are incompatible after reading other posts.

```
<form action="test_result2.php" method="post">

<?php

mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'password');
mysql_select_db('database');



$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT Country FROM engravers Where Country <>'' AND Country IS NOT NULL ORDER by Country";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

    echo "<select name\\='Country'>";
    echo "<option value='$_POST'>Country</option>";
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<option value='" . $row['Country'] . "'>" . $row['Country'] . "</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";

    $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT Year FROM engravers Where Year <>'' AND Year IS NOT NULL ORDER by Year";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    echo "<select name\\='Year'>";
    echo "<option value='$_POST'>Year</option>";
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<option value='" . $row['Year'] . "'>" . $row['Year'] . "</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";

    $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT Engraver1Surname FROM engravers Where Engraver1Surname <> '' AND Engraver1Surname IS NOT NULL ORDER by Engraver1Surname";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    echo "<select name\\='Engraver1Surname'>";
      echo "<option value='$_POST'>Engraver</option>";
      while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
      echo "<option value='" . $row['Engraver1Surname'] . "'>" . $row['Engraver1Surname'] . "</option>";
      }
      echo "</select>";

      $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT Designer1Surname FROM engravers Where Designer1Surname <>'' AND Designer1Surname IS NOT NULL ORDER by Designer1Surname";
      $result = mysql_query($sql);

      echo "<select name\\='Designer1Surname'>";
      echo "<option value='$_POST'>Designer</option>";
      while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
      echo "<option value='" . $row['Designer1Surname'] . "'>" . $row['Designer1Surname'] . "</option>";
      }
      echo "</select>";

     $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT Printer FROM engravers Where Printer <>'' AND Printer IS NOT NULL ORDER by Printer";
      $result = mysql_query($sql);

      echo "<select name\\='Printer'>";
      echo "<option value='$_POST'>Printer</option>";
      while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
      echo "<option value='" . $row['Printer'] . "'>" . $row['Printer'] . "</option>";
      }
      echo "</select>";

          ?>

            <input type="submit" />   
        </form>


        </body>
```

This seems to work OK so I am hoping I can still use it. I'm trying to learn how to use PDO for the results page to protect against injection as I've had dire warnings that my older code was vulnerable. What I've come up with is the following. I know it is wrong because it doesn't work but I can't work out where it is wrong.

```
<?php


 $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database;charset=utf8', 'user', 'password');
 $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
 $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);


 foreach($db->query("SELECT * FROM engravers WHERE $Country = $_POST['Country']", $Year  = $_POST['Year'], $Engraver1Surname = $_POST['Engraver1Surname'], $Designer1Surname = $_POST['Designer1Surname]', $Printer = $_POST['Printer']);
as $row) {
echo $row['Country'].' '.$row['Year'].' '.$row['Engraver1Surname'].' '.$row['Designer1Surname'].' '.$row['Printer']; //etc...
 }
  ?>
```

Am I completely on the wrong track?

Comment: Sidenote: Even using PDO as you're using it now, still leaves you open to SQL injection. Use it with [**(PDO) prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements)

Comment: Plus, using `foreach($db->query` that's not a good idea. You're querying your connection in a loop. This could cause your query to be slower than usual, depending on how much data's being pulled.

Comment: You don't need to escape those quotes, since you are using single quotes for the attribute values.

Comment: Thanks Fred. Looks like that's the way to go. Back to the drawing board.